# My Screen Saver is awry & need help

Tags: imac, screensaver

I have an iMac 21.5" 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5 Macintosh HD - Yosemite. My Screen Saver comes up with foreign words and gobbledygook that I don't understand.  Went into  Finder/library/Screen Savers (this is what is in my Applications) to see what I could do but there is nothing in this folder.  This looks bogus to me. Do you agree and what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Screensavers were developed do deal with issues that affected CRT displays. As nobody makes them anymore, and LCD displays don't have the same issues, we no longer need screensavers. A screensaver running on a flat screen monitor just looks pretty - there is no difference to the operation.

Open System Preferences.

Go to Desktop -> Screen Saver and set the "Start after:" value to Never.

Go to Energy Saver and set "Turn display off..." to whatever value you want.

This actually powers down the screen illumination and most of the GPU.

Comment: Up vote for the CRT reference!  Yep, just eye candy.  Legacy stuff.

Comment: CRTs are still made, and burn-in is still an issue with some non-CRT monitors.

Comment: @tubedogg CRTs are still made, but not for computer monitors. Apple (and pretty much every other domestic computer manufacturer) hasn't sold a CRT in 10 years. The burn-in issue apples to things like plasma displays, also not commonly found on Apple products.

Answer (score 0):

To change your **Screen Saver** go to

```
  > System Preferences... > Desktop & Screen Saver...
```

[image: Icon]

From there you can set the screen saver settings.  I suspect from your question (although it is not clear) that you have the **Word of the Day** screen saver selected.  You can check it's settings or change the screen saver all together.

[image: Screen Saver settings]